# Mouse side buttons doesn't work on (Kali) Linux. What can be the reason for this?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, mouse

When I use the following command, the side buttons of my mouse are not displayed:

`xev | grep button`

What can be the reason for this?

Can someone please help?

Comment: many guesses are possible ... zero information provided ... maybe the mouse is defective

Comment: this is not a forum... it is a question and answer site ... just ask a question that you wish to have answered ... a request like `can someone help?` is not needed ... it is actually not relevant to the question

Comment: @jsotola If I only use the xev command, the side buttons are still not recognized. Can someone please help?

Comment: that is in line with the defective mouse theory ... you already said that in your question above ... why are you repeating yourself?